# WS02CEP GEO DASHBOARD Event dropped at Output Adapter While passing the org.wso2.geo.LocationStream:1.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

WS02CEP Event dropped at Output Adapter While passing the org.wso2.geo.LocationStream:1.0.0. I have attached the exact error below. Can anyone help me to resolve it ?

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.websocket.local.WebsocketLocalEventAdapter} -  Event dropped at Output Adapter 'Geo-Publisher-WebSocketLocal-FusedSpacialEvent' for tenant id '-1234', No clients registered

Comment: Have you resolved this? I met the same problem

Comment: I also have the same problem on EI 6.1.0